# Update field once computed field is calculated

Tags: knockout.js

I have a date field that displays a date:

```
<input type="text" data-bind='value: model.BeginDateTime'>
```

I then have a field that displays the hours from the begining of the month:

```
<input type="text" data-bind='value: model.BeginHour()'>
```

it gets the value from a computed function

```
self.model.BeginHour = ko.computed(function(){

        var dateToConvert = new Date(self.model.BeginDateTime());
        var zeroDate = new Date(dateToConvert.getFullYear(), dateToConvert.getMonth(), 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var millisecondsDifference = (dateToConvert - zeroDate);
        var hoursDifference = (millisecondsDifference / ((1000 * 60) * 60));
        return Math.round(hoursDifference);


});
```

but I need to be able to update the date if the hour value is changed.

An example would be if the date is 2/1/2012 8:00:00 PM the BeginHour value is 20. Now I want to be able to change the value of BeginHour from 20 to 21 and it should update model.BeginDateTime to 2/1/2012 9:00:00 PM.
the conmputed is currently working well for displaying the hours but I am unable to get it to work when I update the hour field.
thanks

Comment: But that would create a circular dependency... you need to rethink what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

computed before used to be called dependentObservable which would have helped you understand where you are going wrong.

When you have a computed referencing model.BeginDateTime that means that computed is dependent on the value of model.BeginDateTime. It will mutate as soon as you change the value of model.BeginDateTime.

Now you seem to want it the other way around, which means you want model.BeginDateTime to be a computed referencing model.BeginHour.

You also can subscribe to change event of properties in ko. e.g.

```
self.model.BeginHour.subscribe(function(newValue){
    console.log("I get called when BeginHour value changes to " + newValue);
});
```